# R data visualization: Is there a way to plot based on emmeans using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am trying to visualize my data separately as a bar graph and as a dot plot connected by a line.

The experimental design includes 2 treatments, 3 levels for each treatment, and 2 diets as independent variables and weight measurement as a dependent variable. Each sample (e.g. treatment "a" level "1" diet "l" is duplicated. Below is a sample data frame (the response variable values are simplified):

```
df <- data.frame(treatment=c('a','a','a','b','b','b','a','a','a','b','b','b',
                             'a','a','a','b','b','b','a','a','a','b','b','b',
                             'a','a','a','b','b','b','a','a','a','b','b','b',
                             'a','a','a','b','b','b','a','a','a','b','b','b'),
                    level=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,
                            1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,
                            1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,
                            1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,
                            1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,
                            1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,
                            1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,
                            1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
                    diet=c('l','l','l','l','l','l','h','h','h','h','h','h',
                           'l','l','l','l','l','l','h','h','h','h','h','h',
                           'l','l','l','l','l','l','h','h','h','h','h','h',
                           'l','l','l','l','l','l','h','h','h','h','h','h'),
                    rep=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                          2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
                          1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                          2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                    weight=c(100,75,50,50,25,12.5,100,75,50,50,25,12.5,
                             100,75,50,50,25,12.5,100,75,50,50,25,12.5,
                             200,150,100,100,50,25,200,150,100,100,50,25,
                             200,150,100,100,50,25,200,150,100,100,50,25))
```

Using a linear mixed model, I see that treatment and level effects are individually significant.

```
fit_df <- lmer(weight ~ treatment*level*diet + (1|rep), data=df)
```

I have also run emmeans to see pairwise contrasts between each combination of treatment and level.

```
(emm_wt <- emmeans(fit_df, specs=pairwise~treatment*level))
```

Then, I want to visualize the result shown below in a bar graph and a dot plot connected by a line. For the bar graph, the y-axis is emmean, x-axis is treatment*level, and error bars show emmean±SE.

```
$emmeans
 treatment level emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 a         1      150.0 7.98 27.7   133.64    166.4
 b         1       75.0 7.98 27.7    58.64     91.4
 a         2      112.5 7.98 27.7    96.14    128.9
 b         2       37.5 7.98 27.7    21.14     53.9
 a         3       75.0 7.98 27.7    58.64     91.4
 b         3       18.8 7.98 27.7     2.39     35.1

Results are averaged over the levels of: diet 
Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

The code below produces something similar to what I am looking for, but I am not sure how to add a line connecting the dots by the treatment (a1 to a3 and b1 to b3)...
It would also be nice to assign colors by the treatment (e.g. red for a and blue for b).

```
plot(emm_wt[[1]],
     CIs=TRUE,
     PIs=TRUE,
     comparisons=TRUE,
     colors=c("black","dark grey","grey","red"),
     alpha=0.05,
     adjust="tukey") +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: plot of the above code]

If anybody has any insights as to how I could visualize this, please let me know. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, using `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df,aes(reorder(trt,level),emmean, group=treatment, color=treatment)) + 
  geom_line(size=2) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("a" = "red", "b"="blue")) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=lower.CL, ymax=upper.CL), size=2,show.legend = F) + 
  geom_point(color="black", size=8) +
  ylim(0,200) + labs(x="Treatment/Level", color="Treatment") + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

Output:
[image: emmeansplot]

Input:

```
df = structure(list(treatment = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"), level = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), emmean = c(150, 75, 112.5, 37.5, 75, 18.8
), SE = c(7.98, 7.98, 7.98, 7.98, 7.98, 7.98), df = c(27.7, 27.7, 
27.7, 27.7, 27.7, 27.7), lower.CL = c(133.64, 58.64, 96.14, 21.14, 
58.64, 2.39), upper.CL = c(166.4, 91.4, 128.9, 53.9, 91.4, 35.1
), trt = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c("a1", 
"a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This plot could be produced using `emmip(emm_wt, level ~ treatment, CIs = TRUE)`